# What are the chanting lyrics in "Song of Freedom"

Tags: doctor-who

At the end of season four of Doctor Who, when Tennant's Doctor is towing the earth back to its proper place, the track playing is "Song of Freedom".

In this track, there are some chanting voices. Does anyone know what they are chanting, in what language? Do the lyrics have any hidden meaning? Or maybe they are only chanting noises, and not necessarily actual words.

Anyone know?

P.S. I wasn't sure if this fit better on Movies & TV or Sci-fi & Fantasy. It's not specifically about the sci-fi plots or technology or species or anything of the show (as far as I can tell), so I opted to put it here. If an admin thinks it'd be better on SciFi&Fant, please move it.

Comment: Does this chanting only exist in the show?  I'm kinda guessing it does based on the translation.  The main issue I see is that this borders on music trivia, but it seems that the piece is directly tied to the show and has a pretty signifigant meaning.

Comment: Yes, the lyrics ***most definitely*** have meaning very specific to the show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At [Feel Good Songs](http://feelgoodsongs.info/song/song-of-freedom) the following appears:
[In Latin:]

> Cum tacent clament
>
> Cum tacent clament
>
> Serva ne
>
> Servan tuter
>
> Sevan servan tuter
>
> Dum inter homines sumus colamus humanitatem
>
> Cum tacent clament
>
> Dum inter homines sumus colamus humanitatem
>
> Cum tacent clament

**English Translation:**

With silence, we shout

With silence, we shout

Without salvation

He provides our salvation

He provides us our salvation

As long as we are among humans, let us be humane

With silence, we shout

As long as we are among humans, let us be humane

With silence, we shout

Answer (score 4):

Here's a video with the Latin lyrics superimposed:

And with a literal translation in English:

[Lyrics and translations by Classicist Penelope Goodman, University of Leeds](http://weavingsandunpickings.wordpress.com/2010/09/09/the-latin-in-murray-golds-vale-decem/)

**Murray Gold’s lyrics**

> Vale Decem...
>   Ad aeternam...
>   Di meliora...
>   Ad aeternam...
>   Vale Decem...
>   Di meliora...
>   Beati...
>   Pacifici...
>   Vale Decem...
>   Alis grave...
>   Ad perpetuam memoriam...
>   Vale Decem...
>   Gratis tibi ago...
>   Ad aeternam...
>   Nunquam singularis...
>   Nunquam...
>   Dum spiro fido...
>   Vale...

**Literal translation**

> Farewell, Ten...
>   To the eternal...
>   (May the) gods (grant you) better (things)...
>   To the eternal...
>   Farewell, Ten...
>   (May the) gods (grant you) better (things)...
>   Blessed...
>   (Are) the peacemakers...
>   Farewell, Ten...
>   Heavy with wings...
>   To perpetual memory...
>   Farewell, Ten...
>   I give you thanks...
>   To the eternal...
>   Never alone...
>   Never...
>   While I breathe I trust...
>   Farewell...

**Mood-appropriate translation**

> Farewell, Ten...
>   On to eternity...
>   The fates be with you...
>   On to eternity...
>   Farewell, Ten...
>   The fates be with you...
>   Oh, blessed he...
>   Who brought us peace...
>   Farewell, Ten...
>   Lay down your burden...
>   We will remember you forever more...
>   Farewell, Ten...
>   We give you thanks...
>   On to eternity...
>   You are not alone...
>   Never...
>   Trust to the last...
>   Farewell...

Comment: I'm trying really hard to hear these words in Song of Freedom, and I can't. Are you sure they're the same as Vale Decem?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it seems that the lyrics to Song Of Freedom are not the same as those of Vale Decem. The lyrics to Song of Freedom seem to be the same as the lyrics to Songs of Captivity and Freedom, both of which begin with "Cum Tacent Clament."

Vale Decem is still an absolutely beautiful song, though, so thanks for posting those lyrics! They just happen to be completely different lyrics than those in Song of Freedom.